# Temporary failure in name resolution -wget in linux

Tags: python, linux, api, wget

Im running python code solution (automation) in linux

As part of the test im calling different api (rest) and connecting to my sql db.

I'm running the solution 24/7

The soultion does

- Call api with wget
- Every 1 min samples the db with query for 60 min max
- Call api again with wget
- Every 1 min samples dc for 10 mins max.

This scenario runs 24/7

Problem is that after 1 hr/ 2hr (inconsistency-can happen after 45 mins for instance) the solution exit with error

> Temporary failutre in name resolution.

It can happen even after 2 perfect cycle as I described above.

After this failure I'm trying to call with wget tens of times and ends with the same error.

After some time it covered by it self.

Want to mention that when it fails with wget on linux,
Im able to call the api via POSTMAN via windows with no problem.

The api calls are for our system (located in aws) and im using dns of our elb..

What could be the oroblem for this inconsistency?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky not knowing with which options you are calling wget and no log output, but since it seems to be a dns issue I would explicitly pass the --dns-servers=your.most.reliable.server to wget.  If it persists I would also pass --append-output=logfile and examine logfile for further clues.

Comment: Thank you.im using several option within the wget call.ill be next to pc on sunday and will add these and check and tell also the flags im using

Comment: But how come it works perfectly when run it via postman in windows using same api with dns and everything

Comment: Intermittent and inconsistent dns problems are common and frustrating.  In my experience it's best to explicitly define your script parameters as much as possible then search the logs for clues if any problems persist.  I would even define you name server by ip address during your troubleshooting if that is possible/reasonable in your situation.  Ideal result is that you will resolve the problem and fully understand what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the fail:
wget http:/host/download 2>/dev/null